How Can I Successfully Transition to a Junior IT Project Manager Role with My Background?
I have spent 3 years in IT recruitment, where I also had some project management responsibilities. I have 4 years of experience in e-commerce (my own business). For the past 7 months, I have been working as a project coordinator at a non-IT company.
I would like to apply for a junior IT PM position, but I see that the current market situation requires at least 3 years of experience, and companies are not giving opportunities to juniors.
What would you recommend to improve my chances of successfully applying for these positions?
Should I complete some training, or take on smaller projects "for free" part-time? I am also available to work as a contractor.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I can't answer your question directly without knowing you or your particular experience. However, it sounds as if you may have some reasonably valid experience. I would suggest that you do the following:

Look at your CV and highlight anything that could possibly be described as PM experience. Really think about this, and understand what this means - remembering that PMs can have to deal with some or all of recruitment, personnel matters, finance, technology, planning, reporting, analysis, and a lot more. Having run your own company is a good thing - you have had to plan, manage resources, etc. so don't underplay this.
Be ready to discuss any or all of these experience areas with potential employers. Don't claim something that is not true, but explain how your experience does relate to project management disciplines.
Try to talk to experienced PMs and validate your claims. They may suggest expanding some bits and / or contracting or minimising others.
Talk to recruitment agencies and "sell" yourself to them. They will help to sell your services to potential employers if they accept the validity of your claimed expertise - or they will highlight gaps or inconsistencies in your CV that you can subsequently improve.
Don't hide jobs that don't directly relate to PM work, but do try to explain how they have helped you to develop in relevant ways.
Consider paying for a PM training course, if you can afford to do so. This will both help you to learn about the role AND demonstrate your commitment to it.

Good luck!
